# Edit Paperspace Objects for Advance Steel

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I have been looking all over for how to edit Advance Steel 2D paperspace Labels through C#. Advance steel has lots of libraries for editing 3D entities. I need references to Advance Steel 2D entities.

```
using Autodesk.AdvanceSteel.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AdvanceSteel.DocumentManagement;
using Autodesk.AdvanceSteel.CADAccess;
using Autodesk.AdvanceSteel.Modelling;
using Autodesk.AdvanceSteel.CADLink.Database;

var oid = UserInteraction.SelectObject();//select label
var obj = DatabaseManager.Open(oid);//obj is always null in 2D paperspace
```

I have tried getting the entity with the basic AutoCAD SDK but I dont find any properties for the Advance Steel Label I can edit in code.

How Does one Edit Advance Steel 2D paperspace entities in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is not an API for accessing paperspace Advanced Steel objects.